# refactor code using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I am struggling on refactoring this (working) code:

```
MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

 List<SelectListItem> selectedItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
 if (type == null) return selectedItems;

if (type == typeof(class1))
             selectedItems = db.class1.ToList().Select(ii => new SelectListItem { Text = ii.Name, Value = ii.Id.ToString() }).OrderBy(si => si.Text).ToList();

if (type == typeof(class2))
             selectedItems = db.class2.ToList().Select(ii => new SelectListItem { Text = ii.Name, Value = ii.Id.ToString() }).ToList();

if (type == typeof(class3))
            selectedItems = db.class3.ToList().Select(ii => new SelectListItem { Text = ii.Name, Value = ii.Id.ToString() }).ToList();

if (type == typeof(class4))
            selectedItems = db.class4.ToList().Select(ii => new SelectListItem { Text = ii.Name, Value = ii.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
```

This code is inside an ASP.NET MVC controller.
Class1 to Class 4 are Model classes.

SelectListItem is just a ModelView class I use to grab an Id and a Name from a Class1, 2, 3 or 4 object. I don't think it s worth posting its code.
So below code just extracts all occurrences of Class1 or 2 or 3 or 4 and converts them into options that will be passed to a View (for a DropDownBox).
I only know the exact Model type at runtime of course (Class1...or 4).

I use Entity Framework with such a DbContext:

```
  public partial class MyDbContext: DbContext
    {
...

        public virtual DbSet<Class1> Class1{ get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Class2> Class2{ get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Class3> Class3{ get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Class4> Class4{ get; set; }
...
    }
```

I am pretty sure I can end up with a clean code with reflection instead of this horrible thing I wrote. But I did not manage to get anything clean that compiles.

Comment: How about using an interface that all classes 1,2,3 and 4 implement that contains name and id and text? This way you want care which model is used.

Comment: Yep, that would work. I ll probably do that if no working refactor is proposed. thx :)

Comment: You should do this in every case. This code exposes a relationship across the models and you can express it with an interface or abstract superclass. Depends on the actual models.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor it as follows:

```
MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
List<SelectListItem> selectedItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

if (type == null)
{
    return selectedItems;
}

var v1 = db.GetType().GetProperty(type.Name).GetValue(db, null);
var v2 = v1.ToList().Select(ii => new SelectListItem { Text = ii.Name, Value = ii.Id.ToString() });

if (type.Name == "class1")
{
    v2 = v2.OrderBy(si => si.Text);
}

v3 = v2.ToList();
```

Sincerely, I doubt this works because of the `var`. You must probably determine the actual classes and define multiple variables. This way the compiler knows that `v1` has a `ToList()` method. Without proper code it is impossible to know which classes to use, but this is just to give you an idea. It obviously requires fixing.

Comment: This is more or less what I tried so far. I gave it a try. Compiler refuses to apply ToList() to v1 since v1 is not an IEnumerable<t>. And we can't cast it to an IEnumerable<t> since we do not know the exact type t.

Comment: Then do a debug and inspect the variable with a breakpoint. Where's the problem? This is a common programming activity that is solved with a *working method*, not with code.

Comment: Obviously, without polimorphism it wouldn't be useful. Is there a superclass? Or a common interface such as `IList`? Define the variable as such or cast to it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a first improvement using genericity and reflection.

I made an extension method of my MyDbContext  class:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> getTable<T>(this MyDbContext db)
{
    List<SelectListItem> ImproItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    if (typeof(T) == null) return ImproItems;


    List<T> Ts = ((IEnumerable<T>) db.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(T).Name).GetValue(db, null)).ToList(); //.Select(ii => new SelectListItem( (T)ii)); //does not work directly
    foreach(dynamic t in Ts)
    {
        ImproItems.Add(new SelectListItem(t));
    }
}
```

Then all I need to do is to make 4 constructors of SelectListItem accepting a Class1, Class2, Class3 and Class4 argument.

Compiler does not accept directly

```
List<dynamic> Ts = ((IEnumerable<T>) db.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(T).Name).GetValue(db, null)).ToList(); //.Select(ii => new ImproItemViewModel( (T)ii));
foreach(dynamic t in Ts)
{
    ImproItems.Add(new ImproItemViewModel(t));
}
```

It cannot convert to a List.

I am pretty sure gurus will still manage to get rid off the foreach but at least I got rid off the 4 if() !

Comment: `ImproItems.AddRange(((IEnumerable<T>) db.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(T).Name).GetValue(db, null)).ToList().Select(t => new SelectListIem(t)))` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I like your question with other perspective like to build dynamic queries. So I tried a different approach to build a dynamic query using Expression Tree. This would be an extension method which will appear with all `IQueryable<>` types.

```
public static class QueryableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetTable<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {

        KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo> sourceDestPropMap1
                                        = new KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo>(
                                            typeof(SelectListItem).GetProperty("Text"), // Text prop of selected item
                                                 typeof(T).GetProperty("Name") // Name prop of T class
                                                 ); 

        KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo> sourceDestPropMap2
                                        = new KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo>(
                                                 typeof(SelectListItem).GetProperty("Value"), // Value prop of Selected Item
                                                 typeof(T).GetProperty("Id")); // Id prop from T class

        var name = "item";
        // -> declare Lambda parameter 'item' of type T i.e. Class1, Class2 etc.
        var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), name);
        // -> Text = item.Id
        var propVal = Expression.Property(paramExpr, sourceDestPropMap2.Value);
        // -> Text = item.Id.ToString()
        var expression = Expression.Call(propVal, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));
        // -> item => new SelectedListItem(Text = item.Name, Value = item.Id.Tostring());
        var projection = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, SelectListItem>>(
                              Expression.MemberInit(
                                Expression.New(typeof(SelectListItem)),
                                new[] {
                                   Expression.Bind(sourceDestPropMap1.Key, Expression.Property(paramExpr, sourceDestPropMap1.Value)),
                                   Expression.Bind(sourceDestPropMap2.Key, expression)
                                }
                              ), paramExpr);

   // -> Class1.Select(item => new SelectedListItem(Text = item.Name, Value = item.Id.Tostring()).ToList()
        return source.Select(projection).ToList();
    }
}
```

Here's the Linq which I was able to generate in `projection` variable so this should be able to work with select.

> item => new SelectListItem() {Text = item.Name, Value = item.Id.ToString()}

Now all you have to do is call the extension method on any of your entity object at run time.

**Usage** -

```
IEnumerable<SelectedListItem> list = db.Class1.GetTable();
```

Although it has more areas for optimization and can be extended to be more generic instead of handling `SelectedItem` as result type.